# Scala Akka AMQP, multiple routing keys

Tags: scala, akka, amqp

Right now you can create a queue consumer with

```
AMQP.ConsumerParameters(...routingKey="key"...)
```

Is there a way to specify multiple keys.
I know in the rabbitmq web interface I can specify multiple routing keys for a queue.
Is there a way to do this programmatically in Akka/AMQP